Method to decomposing Lie Algebra representations into irreducible components
I've been studying Dr. Georgi's text on Lie algebras in particle physics. Per the problems in his text, it should be possible to show that $SU(3)$ can be decomposed in two different ways if one takes the $SU(2)$ sub algebras to be different matrices. I believe it's true that:
$$
SU(3):  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \mathbf{3} = \mathbf{2} \oplus \mathbf{1} \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathbf{8} = \mathbf{3} \oplus \mathbf{2} \oplus \mathbf{2} \oplus \mathbf{1}
$$
where the $\mathbf{8}$ is for the adjoint representation and the $\mathbf{3}$ is the fundamental. I understand that if I diagonalize all the matrices that I can observe what set of matrices act on what elements of a vector in the respective spaces. I also see that when looking at the tensor product of a representation with itself that if I take some tensor $T_{ij}$ in a particular lie group, that I can separate out the trace, symmetric, and antisymmetric portions of an element of the lie group and thus for a particular dimension I can split, say, $\mathbf{n} \otimes \mathbf{n}$ as $\mathbf{(\frac{1}{2} n*(n + 1) - 1)} \oplus (\mathbf{\frac{1}{2} n*(n-1)}) \oplus (\mathbf{1})$.
My question is what exactly is the method to properly decompose representations and products of representations? It's pretty straight forward when the group elements are already block diagonal, but when I'm asked to decompose $\frac{1}{2} \lambda_a \otimes \sigma_2$ and $\frac{1}{2} \lambda_b \otimes \mathbb{1}^{2 \times 2}$, where $\mathbb{1}^{2 \times 2} = diag(1,1)$, for $\ a \in \{1,3,4,6,8\}, \ b \in \{2,5,7\}$, for example, I have no idea how to decompose this.
I see what $SU(2)$'s are preserved, but upon diagonalizing all the matrices, 7 of them only act on the top two and bottom two elements of an 8 dimensional column vector, and 1 of them is completely diagonal. I'm not sure what this would mean for the decomposition; I don't think it's true that for this representation that $\mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{2} = \mathbf{4} \oplus \mathbf{2}$. According to an older post, the matrix $\ S\equiv ( \mathbb{1} +i\sigma_1)/\sqrt{2} \ $ such that $ \ S^\dagger S=\mathbb{1} ~, S^\dagger \sigma_2 S=\sigma_3 \ $ generates a similarity transformation such that this representation decomposes as $\mathbf{3} \oplus \bar{\mathbf{3}}$. How would I derive this? How would I look at these matrices and immediately pick out that I need to use this matrix to properly decompose this representation? Do these matrices describe anything physical?
TL/DR: I'm not sure what the method to decomposing representations and products of representations into irreducible parts is.

This is certainly not true. The representations you are talking about, $\mathbf{3}$ and $\mathbf{8}$, are irreducible and so cannot be decomposed into smaller ones.
Moreover $\mathbf{3}\otimes \mathbf{3}$ splits as $\bar{\mathbf{3}}\oplus \mathbf{6}$ (antisymmetric and symmetric parts) there is no "trace" part here. That occurs in $\mathbf{3}\otimes \bar{\mathbf{3}}$ which splits as $\mathbf{8}\oplus \mathbf{1}$ (adjoint representation and "trace").
In general, computing the decomposition is quite involved. There are programs that will do it for you e.g. LiE. I heartily recommend reading Humphreys' book on the subject (Introduction to Lie algebras and representation theory) or Hall's Lie groups, Lie algebras and representation theory or Fulton and Harris's Representation theory.

Thanks for your response. I realized I wrote $\mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{3}$ without thinking. I edited accordingly for some representation of dimension $\mathbf{n}$ that's greater than $\mathbf{3}$. I will check out this text, thank you.

@DingleGlop it it still isn't true I'm afraid. The only thing you have guaranteed is that it splits into symmetric and antisymmetric parts (which may split further). If there is an invariant nondegenerate symmetric (resp. antisymmetric) bilinear form on the original representation you get a copy of $\mathbf{1}$ in the symmetric (resp. antisymmetric) part.
